# Reserved word “function”

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to make infinite scrolling but I get this error?

> ExecJS::RuntimeError in Pages#profile
>       Showing C:/Users/mojo/rails/railsapp/apps/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:
>       SyntaxError: [stdin]:4:19: reserved word "function"

post.coffee

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($('.pagination').length) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          var url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
          if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
            $('.pagination').text("Please Wait...");
            return $.getScript(url);
          }
        });
        return $(window).scroll();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Your `post.coffee` is JavaScript, not CoffeeScript. Either rewrite it in CoffeeScript or rename it to `post.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript and coffeescript syntaxes are not mutually compatible.

In your case, the file content is javascript where as the filename indicates it is a coffeescript file so sprockets is trying to parse it as coffeescript.

You can rename `post.coffee` to `post.js` to resolve this.